# Jquery on click any element with class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make an on click event that hides the element that is clicked if it has a certain class, but what I tried isn't working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.alert').on('click', function(){
        $(this).slideUp(150);
    });
});
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you want all elements with class .alert to be hidden? Or why is it not working exactly?

Comment: We might need to see your HTML to figure this out

Comment: I tested your code locally and it worked fine . . . any errors in the console?

Comment: It seems that your `.alert` element has `display: block !important;` style or something similar. Check it in your web console.

Comment: Just found the issue has nothing to do with my js, thanks anyway!

Comment: Would you mind sharing your problem / solution?

Comment: @showdev my problem is that I have three `.alert` divs, which come in with `display: none` and they are shown in different stages, but when a user clicked on them, the clicked one should hide. But I have one of them, that, for some reason isn't hiding :/

Comment: Oh, maybe I misunderstood. It sounded like you had discovered what was causing the issue and that it wasn't related to the JavaScript. I was just hoping to find out the problem and solution you discovered.

Answer (score 2):

Normally this should hide the current element clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.alert').on('click', function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

If you want to hide all elements with the class:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.alert').on('click', function(){
        $('.alert').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: `slideUp` should work just fine to (does, in fact, when I test it locally).

Comment: Nevermind, I discovered it has to do with another thing, sorry :/

Comment: Your answer was right though

Answer (score 0):

There is a JQuery `hide()` method

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.alert').on('click', function(){
        $(".yourclass").hide();
    });
});
```

or something like this..
also take a look at: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Update:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#element").click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass("hide")){
              $(this).slideUp(200);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <button id="element" class="hide">Element 1</button>

    <button id="element" class="show">Element 2</button>    

  </body>
</html>
```

http://codepen.io/woidfeeee/pen/vOXQRL?editors=100

Comment: sorry Vince was faster.. ;)

Comment: `slideUp` is just an animated version of `hide` . . . there should be no need to change that function choice here.

Answer (score -1):

> ...that hides the element that is clicked if it has a certain class...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.alert').on('click', function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('certain-class'){
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Note, you only need to pass in the class name without the `.`

Comment: This is also redundant.

Comment: @TommyDDD, how is this redundant?

Comment: nvm you changed it from $('.alert').hide(); => $(this).hide(); I'm assuming .alert is the "certain-class" he is looking for. This doesn't seem to answer what he is asking for.

Comment: @TommyDDD, ...that hides the element that is clicked if it has a certain class..., sigh, oh well